# Angular material broken on Chrome 69 update

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angular-material

So, after chrome update, my page needs to be resized to be well seen. Any ideas?

This is with default zoom (100%):
[image]

Then, this is how it should look (resized to 90%):
[image]

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Does the page have the `viewport` set to something unusual?

Comment: I dont think so...
`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />`

Comment: Have you tried it on a different computer? Perhaps a virtual machine with a copy of Chrome 69 that has never visited the site before.

Comment: Yes @AndrewMorton, it happens everywhere all of a sudden with chrome

Answer (score 1):

Decision:

```css
md-input-container {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Hi Roman, what do you mean by Decision:? Anyway, what you posted does nothing at all.

Comment: Hi, i have same issue, this example fixed my problem, pls try this:
* { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }